# Share authentication cookie between sites

Tags: .net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to share an authentication cookie between different applications in .net core 2.2.

Below code is from application 1 (comportocertlogin.local) startup.cs:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SVN\RS.3C\trunk\SourceCode\ComportoAdmin\ComportoAdmin.CertificateLogin"))
            .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

        //services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        //{
        //    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
        //    options.Cookie.Domain = ".local";
        //});

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Login";
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
            options.Cookie.Domain = ".local";
            options.Cookie.Path = "/";
            options.DataProtectionProvider =
                DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SVN\RS.3C\trunk\SourceCode\ComportoAdmin\ComportoAdmin.CertificateLogin"));
        });
```

Then in application 1 I have the code below for creating authentication cookie and redirection to application 2

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int userId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //bool isValid = userId == 2; // TODO Validate the username and the password with your own logic

            //if (!isValid)
            //{
            //    ModelState.AddModelError("", "username or password is invalid");
            //    return Page();
            //}

            // Create the identity from the user info
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userId.ToString()));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserId", userId.ToString()));

            // Authenticate using the identity
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false });

            return Redirect("https://scomportoadmin.local/searchUserAccount");
        }

        return Page();
    }
```

In application 2 (scomportoadmin.local) startup.cs I have the following code:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });



        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SVN\RS.3C\trunk\SourceCode\ComportoAdmin\ComportoAdmin.CertificateLogin"))
            .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

        //services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        //{
        //    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
        //    options.Cookie.Domain = ".local";
        //});

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/login";
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
            options.Cookie.Domain = ".local";
            options.Cookie.Path = "/";
            options.DataProtectionProvider =
                DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SVN\RS.3C\trunk\SourceCode\ComportoAdmin\ComportoAdmin.CertificateLogin"));

        });
   services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/SearchUserAccount");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/EditCreateUserAccount");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/RegisterUserAccount");
        }).
        SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Something is missing because I cant access the pages SearchUserAccount and EditCreateUserAccount in application 2. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In the `.AddCookie` config of each app, you're setting a data protection provider directly with no shared app name. This isn't even necessary, as you've already configured a shared data protection provider at the application level, which will be used to encrypt the cookies by default.

Long and short, just remove the line where you're setting `options.DataProtectionProvider` for the cookie on both apps and you should be good to go.

Comment: I removed options.DataProtectionProvider from both startup but I still cant access the pages. Any ideas on why?